# How to deep search through every field in a complex object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, object, ups

I'm using C#, ASP.NET, I use UPS API Tracking to get the Delivery Info, upon making the request, I got back an object (trackResponse) which is very complex and has a lot of field/property or other object embedded inside it.

How do I program to search for every possible value field (string/int/double) in that object?

Basically I want a method like this:

```
public static bool FindValueInObject(object Input, object SearchValue)
    {
        Type MyType = Input.GetType();
        var props = typeof(MyType).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}  PropertyValue: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(mco, null)));

            Type ObjectType = propertyInfo.GetType();
            Type SearchType = SearchValue.GetType();

            object ObjectValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(Input, null);

            if (ObjectType == SearchType)
            {
                if(ObjectValue == SearchValue)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FindValueInObject(ObjectValue, SearchValue);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But the code above didn't work. Please take a look.

Comment: Use reflection.  Get all the types in your object and then iterate through each one to inspect the values.

Comment: Is there any general method that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mco = new MyComplexObject();
            mco.MyDate1 = DateTime.Now;
            mco.MyDate2 = DateTime.Now;
            mco.MyDate3 = DateTime.Now;
            mco.MyString1 = "String1";
            mco.MyString2 = "String1";
            mco.MyString3 = "String1";


            var props = typeof(MyComplexObject).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in props)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}  PropertyValue: {1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(mco, null)));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class MyComplexObject
    {
        public string MyString1 { get; set; }
        public string MyString2 { get; set; }
        public string MyString3 { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate1 { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate3 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I specify so that I can only search for string field only?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with coding - it's only a matter of time and resources.  You would need to add recursion to the logic to scan internal objects.

Comment: I will try it soon and let you know asap.

Comment: I tried to create a recursive function to find a string in a complex object but failed. Basically, I just want to know if the string value is in that object or not (True/False). So the method look like this: public bool isThisValueInThisObject(object thisObject, string Value)

Comment: You need to post your code if you want help. This is not a site where people write code for you.